# Find the antiderivative $F(x)$ for each function $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

## 1. $f(x) = \sin x \cos x$

So I've already solved this but I just want to double check my answer. I got $1/2 \sin^2(x)$ or $1/2 \sin^2(x) + c, \quad c\in\Bbb R$ as my answer.

## 2. $f(x) = x^{\frac 13} + 2x^{\frac 13}$

I got $\frac 94 x^{4/3} + c$ as my answer.

Comment: These are really obvious solutions. You can differentiate the solution and get your answer. No need to ask MSE .

Comment: your answers are correct.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Thank you for your successive edit.

Comment: As a first time calc student they're not obvious to me which is why I asked, to get affirmation that I'm moving in the right direction. But I appreciate the input. @Pritam

Comment: @hera I understand but as these are really basic ones I'll just suggest you to be confident about it and also have alternate ways to verify yours in order to be a good problem solver.

Answer (score 1):

as requested only answers

$$- \frac14 \cos 2x +c$$

$$ \frac94 x^{\frac43} + c $$

Comment: Thank you for your successive edit.

Comment: @narasimham Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

Your ans $\frac{1}{2} \sin^2x + C$ was also right. As this is a indefinite integral you may get different looking antiderivatives but if these were definite integral, the ans would always be same doesn't matter how you solve.

See that $\frac{1}{2} \sin^2x + C = \frac{1}{4} 2sin^2x + C= \frac{1}{4} (1- cos2x) = - \frac{1}{4} \cos2x + (\frac{1}{4}+C) = - \frac{1}{4} \cos2x + C' $

Here just the arbitrary constant changed.